# Why has the selector class an internal Constructor?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, selector

I tried to derive from the Selector class cause I need a similar functionality as the ListBox but it is no ListBox. 
I had a look at the signature of the Selector class and it is (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector(v=vs.95).aspx)

```
public abstract class Selector : ItemsControl, 
ISupportInitialize
```

But the problem is that the constructor is internal. So it is not possible to derive from this class outside the assembly (ListBox and ComboBox are in this assembly).

I now derived from the ListBox to achieve my goal, but my question is:

**Why has the selector class an internal Constructor?**

Answer (score 0):

Because the `Selector` class is `abstract`. You can't create instances of abstract classes, and the easiest way to make sure you can't even do that by mistake (in a regular way) is to not make a constructor available.

I don't see an entry for the constructor on the MSDN, but my bet is that it's probably a `protected` constructor, not an `internal` one.

But from what I can see, nothing stops you from deriving from `Selector`, and create your custom implementation.

**Edit:**
Reflector shows the constructor to be `internal` indeed, so no deriving...

Comment: Hi, it is not possible. Cause if you want to derive from a class, the c'tor has to be accessable. Example: public abstract class MyClass
    {
        private MyClass(){}
    }

    public class MySecondClass : MyClass
    {
        
    } <= is not possible

Comment: @TerenceJackson: That's why I updated the answer (see the "Edit") ;) It's a bit strange, the usual thing to do is create a protected constructor. My guess is the designers had a definite requirement for the class to be not inheritable, and so chose to make it internal instead of protected.

Comment: Sry for the comment ;) I was typing already and did'nt recognize your Edit. I think it is strange that the class is public but the c'tor is not protected or public...

Comment: @TerenceJackson: That's covered in the first part of the answer: It's a good design practise to have an abstract class only implement protected constructors, to avoids the possibility of "newing" an instance the regular way. The class (and its descendants) themselves may expose public behvaiour , hence the need for it to be public. There are more classes that are public, without having a public constructor. The designers first intention was probably to eliminate the possibility of descendants outside their assembly, and were thus only left with the option of adding an internal constructor.